# How to remove only the first tag from a string xml, c#

Tags: c#, xml, string

I'm getting data from a web service. It returns a string with `xml` tags:

```
<price>
 <Amount>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
 </Amount>
</price>
```

Now I want remove only the first `<Amount>` tag from this string. that means I want only this

```
<price>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
</price>
```

How can I do that?

this is how I get webservice xml response in to a string.

```
string result = "";
string webserviceUrl ="somerl.";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
result = client.DownloadString(webserviceUrl);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? I'd parse it as an XML document, manipulate it, then convert it back to a string if you need to...

Comment: yes I treid to replace using `mystring.Replace` but, it replace all `Amount` tags.I'm new to c#, and do not have lot experience.

Comment: can you share some code on how your handling the XML at the moment.

Comment: You should absolutely *not* do this with string operations. It's XML - parse it with an XML API.

Comment: is there a reason youre handling the xml as a string rather than xml?

Comment: I put string into data tables.

Comment: are you putting the entire xml string into the table? or are you putting the node values in the tables?

Comment: node values(put data in  to columns according to tagnames )

Answer (score 2):

Thats the simpliest way to get this structure:

```
var doc = XElement.Load("File1.xml");
var amounts = doc.Elements("Amount").ToList();
amounts.ForEach(x =>
{
    var element = x.Element("Amount");
    x.RemoveNodes();
    x.Value = element.Value;
});
```

But its totally hardcoded. For the future you can use parsing xml to c# objects with XmlSerializer or use XSLT transformations, which is more prefferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
_doc.LoadXml("<price><Amount><Amount>100</Amount></Amount></price>");

XmlDocument _newXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode _rootNode = _newXmlDoc.CreateElement("price");
_newXmlDoc.AppendChild(_rootNode);
XmlNode _priceNode = _newXmlDoc.CreateElement("Amount");
_priceNode.InnerText = _doc.LastChild.InnerText;
_rootNode.AppendChild(_priceNode);
Console.WriteLine(_newXmlDoc.OuterXml);
```